# Write a query to swap values in a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have mistakenly inserted wrong data in table rows, now I want to swap the data.
Male in place of Female and vice-versa.

[image]

Following is the correct data I am expecting -

[image]

Comment: Update Customer
Set Gender = 
Case 
when Gender='Male' then 'Female'
When Gender='Female' then 'Male' 
End

Comment: or     Update Customer
Set Gender=
Case
When Gender='Male' then 'Female'
Else 'Male'
End

Comment: How to achieve same using temp table?

Comment: If you require an answer use a temp variable or table, you need to indicate that in your question. Also, you should indicate why an answer **not** using a temp variable/table is not sufficient for your question.

Comment: Could you explain why you want a temp table or what you mean with it, it is not necessary for your current question, but if you provide more details is easier to understand what you want

Answer (score 9):

Simple update works:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET 
col1 = CASE WHEN col1 = 'male' THEN 'female' ELSE 'male' END,
col2 = CASE WHEN col2 = 'female' THEN 'male' ELSE 'female' END
```

Result: row values will be swap.

I hope, It will work for you.

Comment: Thanks Piyush, that's I already have done. I am expecting answer using Temp variable.

Comment: You can use temp variable also but that is not good practice because there will be some complexity and you can refer this link http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/How-to-swap-data-between-columns-in-SQL-Server-874.php

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET Gender = CASE Gender
                  WHEN 'Male' THEN 'Female'
                  WHEN 'Female' THEN 'Male'
                  ELSE Gender
             END;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/429830)**</kbd>

Please note that other values than `male/female`  like `N/A` or `NULL` will remain the same.

---

If you want to do it only for specified names use:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET Gender = CASE
               WHEN Name IN ('Geetha', 'Radha') THEN 'Female'
               WHEN Name IN ('Ram', 'Syam', 'Ravi') THEN  'Male'
             END
WHERE Name IN ('Ram', 'Syam', 'Geetha', 'Radha', 'Ravi');
```

Comment: Please reply me the answer using Temp variable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want a temp table if you can do it with a single update

But maybe this fits what you are looking for

```
SELECT TOP 0 * 
INTO #tmp 
FROM YourTable

UPDATE T
SET gender = 'male'
OUTPUT Inserted.* INTO #tmp
FROM YourTable T
WHERE gender = 'female'

UPDATE T
SET gender = 'female'
FROM YourTable
WHERE gender = 'male' --Irrelevant for this case but assuming that you have different values
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Temp WHERE name = T.name) -- Exclude the "swapped" records
```

Or maybe you just want a temp table to confirm the changes before update them.... i am trying to guess

```
DECLARE @swap1 VARCHAR(20) = 'male', @swap2 VARCHAR(20) = 'female'

SELECT * 
INTO #tmp
FROM YourTable

UPDATE #tmp 
    SET gender = CASE 
        WHEN gender = @swap1 THEN @swap2 
        WHEN gender = @swap2 THEN @swap1 
        ELSE gender END

SELECT * FROM #tmp

UPDATE A
SET Gender = T.gender
FROM YourTable A
JOIN #tmp T ON A.name = T.name

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below script to swap values between 2 rows

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempTable

CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(
     ROW_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
     SEQUENCE_NO    INT,
     ID INT
)

DECLARE @Id INT = 24780, --Row Id

DECLARE @NewPosition INT = -1; -- (Move Up or Move Down +1 for Up and -1 For Down)
DECLARE @SEQUENCE_NO INT = 0;  

INSERT INTO #TempTable
SELECT  SEQUENCE_NO ,ID
            FROM TABLE_NAME S
    WHERE ID = @Id 

SET @SEQUENCE_NO = (SELECT SEQUENCE_NO FROM #TempTable)

INSERT INTO #TempTable
SELECT  SEQUENCE_NO AS SNO,ID
            FROM TABLE_NAME S
    WHERE ID  <> @Id   
    AND SEQUENCE_NO = (@SEQUENCE_NO + @NewPosition) -- (Move Up or Move Down +1 for Up and -1 For Down)

--Add check point here temp table to have 2 exact records 

;WITH x AS (SELECT  ID, SEQUENCE_NO FROM #TempTable WHERE ROW_ID = 1)   
   , y AS (SELECT ID, SEQUENCE_NO FROM #TempTable  WHERE ROW_ID = 2) 
UPDATE #TempTable
SET    SEQUENCE_NO = z.SEQUENCE_NO
FROM  (
   SELECT x.ID, y.SEQUENCE_NO FROM x,y
   UNION  ALL
   SELECT y.ID, x.SEQUENCE_NO FROM x,y
   ) z
WHERE #TempTable.ID = z.ID;


UPDATE SI
    SET SI.SEQUENCE_NO = T.SEQUENCE_NO -- (Swap Values here)
    FROM TABLE_NAME SI
        JOIN #TempTable T ON SI.ID = T.ID
```